# Find the closest set of points to another set

Tags: algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have two sets, ***A*** and ***B***, with *N* and *M* points in *R^n* respectively. I know that *N* < *M* always.

The distance between two points, **P** and **Q**, is denoted by *d(* **P**,**Q** *)*. As the problem is generic, this distance could be any function (e.g. Euclidean distance).

I want to find the closest subset of ***B*** to ***A***. Mathematically I would say, I want to find the subset ***C*** of ***B*** with size *N* with the minimal global distance to ***A***. The global distance between ***A*** and ***C*** is given by

```
D(A,C) = min([sum(d(P_i,Q_i),i=1,N) with P_i in A and Q_i in C* for C* in Permutations of C])
```

I've been thinking about this problem and I did an algorithm that get a local optimum, but not necessarily the optimal:

Step 1) Find the nearest point of each point of ***A*** in ***B***. If there are no points repeated, I found the optimal subset and finish the algorithm. However, if there are points repeated, go to step 2.

Step 2) Compare their distances (of course I compare the distance between points with the same closest point). The point with the minimal distance keeps the point previously found and the others change their *desired* point for the "next" closest point that have not been selected for another point yet.

Step 3) Check if all the points are different. If they are, finish. If not, go back to step 2.

Any idea? Trying all the combinations is not a good one (I should calculate M!/(M-N)! global distances)

Comment: Did you try the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm)?

Comment: Could you define the global distance more accurately? Now it looks like it's "matching up" pairs with equal index, but they come out of sets so that's undefined

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I didn't know it. However I should apply this method to M!/((M-N)! * N!) subsets of B, right?

Comment: @harold I changed the definition to something more accurate

Comment: @sebacastroh: no, you might extend A with (M-N) "empty" elements (with zero distance to all elements in B), then apply the Hungarian algorithm.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev yes, definitely it is what I was looking for. Please write it as an answer then I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If M = N, this problem could be formulated as minimum-weight perfect matching in a bipartite graph or, in other words, an assignment problem. A well-known method for solving an assignment problem is the [Hungarian algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

To make Hungarian algorithm applicable in the case N < M, you could extend set **A** with (M-N) additional elements (each having zero distance to all elements of **B**).